# Redirect to popup window after alert message show using asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to show alert message after alert message confirmed i want to display another page .That  page url is url="**var params = ['height='+screen.height,'width='+screen.width,'fullscreen=yes'].join(',');var popup = window.open('ReportViewer.aspx?Option=DeliveryOrder1&DONO=HQ1700000149&Report=SalesInvoice&CustomerName=PUAN+YATI&Address1=NO 1179 PERSIARAN PUTERI 3/2 DSN,&Address2=PUTERI 3/2 TAMAN CHANDAN PUTERI, KUALA KANSAR PERA&Country=MALAYSIA&Phone=               &ZipCode=33000               &subtotal=14.00&totalvalue=14.00&gst=0.00&TotalDiscount=0.00&NetTotal=14.00', '_blank', params);popup.moveTo(0, 0);"**

my code:

```
protected void btn_CreatePo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
 if (result == "True")
                                {
                                    string url = btn_poprint();//edit23/06
                                  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "Alert_CodeBehind(' Delivery Order " + txt_PrintDO.Text + " is Successfully Converted to PO ');window.location='"+ url +"' ", true);

           return;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                  //  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Hide", "<script> document.getElementById('li_ListView').style.display = 'block';</script>", true);
                                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Up_Detail, typeof(string), "Alert", "Alert_CodeBehind('Error in Converting ')", true);
                                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "test", "<script>document.getElementById('a14').className = 'active_tab'</script>");
                                    return;
                                }

}
```

I want to display alert message after alert message confirmed the given url page will be  show.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing, please post with required error details.

Comment: @ Ipsit Gaur  i am edited my post. The alert is not displayed and also page will not be redirected. I just don't know  what is the problem.